# Option buttons on form for database connection

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have 2 forms and on the first form, I have a label to open the second form. The second form is all about database connection options. I have 2 frame controls. The first frame is named frOpts and has 3 option buttons: Prod,Cert and Dev. The second frame is frType with SQL connection options either login using ad or using a SQL login. When SQL login is selected, 2 text boxes for username and pass are enabled and go from grey to white. I also have a module that is doing all of the work. How do I pass these parameters to the Module that is building the SQL connection string? Do I use a global variable in the module? Also, how would I send the right parameter from the option buttons to my main module? I've googled as much as I consider appropriate before asking. I was using a simple test with a command button on this form with this code:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

 Select Case frOpts
  Case 1: MsgBox "Prod"
  Case 2: MsgBox "Cert"
  Case 3: MsgBox "Dev"
 End Select

'Me.Hide

End Sub
```

but that is giving me a Type mismatch. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. So my question is: What is the best way to do what I'm trying to achieve.

**Update**

Here is what I ended up with:

**UserForm1**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 UserForm2.Show (False)

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Me.Show (False)

End Sub
```

**UserForm2**

```
Public xOpt As Integer
Public xTxt As String
Public xType As Integer
Public xTxt2 As String


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Select Case xOpt
    Case 1: xTxt = "Prod"
    Case 2: xTxt = "Cert"
    Case 3: xTxt = "Dev"
End Select

Select Case xType
    Case 1: xTxt2 = "AD login"
    Case 2: xTxt2 = "SQLLogin"
End Select

Module1.BuildString xTxt, xTxt2
Unload UserForm2

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    xOpt = 1
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    xOpt = 2
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    xOpt = 3

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()

    xType = 1

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton5_Click()

    xType = 2

End Sub
```

**Module1**

```
Public Sub BuildString(sOpts As String, sType As String)


sConn = sOpts & " " & sType
Debug.Print sConn

End Sub
```

Thanks for your Help Justin. I couldn't have done it without you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set both forms to `ShowModal = False`

**In the first form:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm2.Show
    UserForm2.xOpts = frOpts
End Sub
```

**In the second form:**

```
Public xOpts As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox xOpts
End Sub
```

**Edit per comments:**

Try this as a full mock up in a new sheet:

Both with `ShowModal=False` and 1 Command Button.

UserForm1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm2.Show (False)
    UserForm2.xOpt = "3"
End Sub
```

UserForm2:

```
Public xOpt As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print xOpt
End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I tried it in my existing code first and then when I couldn't get it to work, I created a new blank workbook and just created the 2 forms and set both to showmodal=false and pasted in the code. It always turns up 0. Any clue why?

Comment: I updated it with the full code for a mock up. The 2nd button prints 3 for me. Do you still get 0 ?

Comment: This works fine with the 3 hardcoded but if I add a frame control with 3 option buttons and change the 3 to frOpts, It always comes out 0.

Comment: In form 1, where are you declaring frOpts and how are you setting the value?  I would add Dim frOpts as Integer at the top of Form1's code, then add 3 OptionButtonX_Click() to update the value each time one of them is clicked.